# tmutil status shows time remaining but Time Machine preference pane says "Calculating time remaining"

Tags: time-machine, big-sur

all. I'm running macOS 11.4. I using a new Time Machine backup destination and want to know how long it's going to take to finish. The Time Machine preference pane continually says *Calculating time remaining…*. However, `tmutil status` lists a `TimeRemaining` property, and it seems to be going down consistently.

Question: is `TimeRemaining` reliable and if so, how do I interpret it.

`man tmutil | grep TimeRemaining` gives me nothing, as do `man tmutil | grep Remaining` and `man tmutil | grep remaining`.

Thanks!

```
Backup session status:
{
    BackupPhase = Copying;
    ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
    DateOfStateChange = "2023-05-26 16:29:15 +0000";
    DestinationID = "A895A939-B045-4714-8C66-3CDF4D861BC1";
    DestinationMountPoint = "/Volumes/path/to/destination";
    FirstBackup = 1;
    Progress =     {
        Percent = "0.4298995862004921";
        TimeRemaining = 727679;
        "_raw_Percent" = "0.4298995862004921";
        "_raw_totalBytes" = 855037718528;
        bytes = 367580361381;
        files = 806898;
        totalBytes = 855037718528;
        totalFiles = 2533396;
    };
    Running = 1;
    Stopping = 0;
}
```

Comment: Might also be worth to look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/162464/489896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. The `TimeRemaining` field is just the time in seconds.

It's hard to figure that out in the beginning when there's so much variability in the estimate toward the beginning. I found every few seconds, `TimeRemaining` would go down but not but sometimes by thousands and sometimes by just a few.

**Answer Source 1**: [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/371762/68172), which I initially had opened but dismissed as not answering the question, links to a [utility on GitHub](https://github.com/tjluoma/textbar-timemachine/blob/master/textbar-timemachine.sh). Especially helpful is this line:

`READABLE_TIME=$(seconds2readable.sh "$TIME_REMAINING")`

**Answer Source 2**: My backup finally is giving me an estimated time of 9 hours (after two days of running with no estimate). The output of `tmutil` is:

`TimeRemaining = 33144;`

And 33144 / 60 / 60 ≈ 9.20677

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this for Big Sur but on Ventura, you can just get a percentage of the backup and how much data has been backed up from the menu bar. (See [Back up your Mac with Time Machine - Check backup status](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201250#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20Time%20Machine%20menu,time%20of%20the%20latest%20backup.) for more info)

[image]

To check that `tmutil status` gives you the right infos, you can check if the menu bar option is an approximation of `Percent`.